# Add 30 minutes in time

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add 30 minutes in time but it doesn't display correctly, please help me. Where is the mistake in my code?

The minutes display like a garbage value...

```html
  
<div id="time"></div>

<script>
function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
  }
  return i;
}

function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
   
 var m = today.setMinutes(today.getMinutes()+30);//**here I am adding plus 30 mint but not showing correct**
 
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  // add a zero in front of numbers<10
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);

//Minutes display like garbage value.... 

  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  t = setTimeout(function() {
    startTime()
  }, 500);
}
startTime();
</script>
```

Please review my code and correct it.

Comment: What does this question have to do with Java?

Comment: today.setMinutes(today.getMinutes()+30) does not return the minutes....

Comment: even if it did return the minutes you should check if it's > 30

Answer (score -1):

You're nesting two different functions, I don't know why.

This line:

```
var m = today.setMinutes(today.getMinutes()+30);
```

Should be:

```
var m = today.getMinutes()+30
```

If you run the code snippets it works.

```html
  
<div id="time"></div>

<script>
function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
  }
  return i;
}

function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  
  // CORRECTION HERE
  var m = today.getMinutes()+30;
 
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  // add a zero in front of numbers<10
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);

//Minutes display like garbage value.... 

  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  t = setTimeout(function() {
    startTime()
  }, 500);
}
startTime();
</script>
```

Comment: I'll have to wait to see what happens in 17 minutes

Comment: If it's 6:30PM though, this will just display `18:60:00`.

Comment: @vrugtehagel Question was adding +30 to current minutes

Comment: thanks for your time dear, but mints will show like 60 I want to see Mints till 59 and then next hours start.